# Installing Wordpress and drupal on same machine

Tags: wordpress, drupal, installation, drupal-6

I am trying to install wordpress and drupal on same server. Using WAMP.  I have installed both WP and Drupal under wwww directory.

In Wordpress CiviCRM works fine.
Drupal installation went through.

issue 1 :

Installing civiCRM module through URL option or by choosing tar.gz file is not working. I didn't even get an error message. Just I am again seeing the "Install module" page again.

issue 2:

Did the alternate option given in step 2 in this link https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7

when I go to step 4, http:///sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php 
I am getting the error shown in the screenshot. It identifies as wordpress installation instead of drupal.  [image]

Comment: Can you please look in <webroot>/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php and confirm that your civicrm.settings.php is reporting that your CMS is Drupal and not WordPress?

Comment: Are you trying to have one instance of CiviCRM accessed by both Drupal and WordPress?

Comment: no... separate civiCRM instances... the last thing I tried is reinstalling wamp and tried drupal's CiviCRM. Even that is failing even without wordpress. No idea why. First time I am using both WP and drupal. This is the first module I am trying to install. I tried my best to ensure there is no mistake in process of installing module.

Comment: Ok... got what the issue. I downloaded latest drupal. that is drupal 8.x.x ... CiviCRM version exists only for drupal 7... Now I am facing different issue. but this is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... got what the issue. I downloaded latest drupal. that is drupal 8.x.x ... CiviCRM version exists only for drupal 7... Now I am facing different issue. but this is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You're installing Civi/Drupal and Civi/WP on ... Windows? What's the motivation for doing this?

If this is an R&D environment and your machine is up to the task I think this would all work much better as a pair of Linux virtual machines running under Virtual Box.

My day to day machine is a MacBook Pro with 16 gig and an SSD for storage. I could easily run two Linux VMs as I describe and still have room for other activities. The Lubuntu (lightweight Ubuntu) distro only needs about five gig of space for a minimal install, it's much more efficient than full Ubuntu. If you're wanting CentOS I have no great wisdom to offer there, haven't found a lightweight distro based on that.

Comment: Thanks for your insights... I am just a newbie in both WordPress and Drupal. I am trying out civicrm for my organization. I saw some reports that work in Drupal does not work in WordPress. So just testing the waters...

Comment: If you're going to host it, I presume it won't be on Windows. If your machine can stand it, a Virtual Box solution would get you out of debugging Windows and into working on the system.

Comment: It is not going to be on web. Going to be used in local network on windows. Any issues with this setup?